# Tag rename hierarchical -> hierarchy

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tagging, retag-request

I suggest renaming the tag `hierarchical` to `hierarchy` which is both easier to write and more accepted. `hierarchical` is the  Queen's English. In Murica' we can also spell it `hierarchal` and this would skirt that issue.

Answer (score 1):

I originally created [hierarchical](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hierarchical) as a target for two synonyms containing the word hierarchical.

On reflection, [hierarchy](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hierarchy) would have been a better name, so I have renamed it as requested.

```
updating post history, 133 rows affected
updating posts, 113 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [hierarchy] and [hierarchical] complete
remapping 2 synonyms
3 favorite and ignored tags remapped
53 tracked tag badges were remapped
```

Renaming is easily undone in case there is an outcry.

Comment: you're on fire. I'm going to start calling you Nov 24 named after all the glory.